# how to set any month as first month in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, strftime

This is my data frame:

```
Name       ID              Date   weekNumber
Joey    jhjhfjhaslfkjsj 2021-03-03  09
Archie  buwuhsjjwj      2021-03-11  10
Sam     sidnmnn         2021-03-16  11
Pam     xfxmndnsnn      2021-03-06  09
Tam     pynmbhvsgv      2021-04-21  16
Kirk    wdjnccjsh       2021-05-08  18
Stark   sjdsbmdnssn     2021-04-07  14
Lily    sdkhsjnzm       2021-04-08  14
Raul    jdjkxmsnlakdn   2021-04-09  14
```

In this my first month is march i want week number should start with march month and not January. How to do that?

Comment: I cannot understand your question, would you please explain it a bit more? And in your code, the ```weekNumber```  is starting with march month.

Comment: i want my week number count to start with march and not January, so for example if my date is  1-03-2021 its week number should return week number 1 not 9 as its week number.

Answer (score 0):

I think, try Checking the month No.
Here, it is 3, and Average there are 4.34524 weeks per month (According to Google), so The multiply 2 (Month - 1) by 4.34524 and round it of

```
Month = 3
months_before_current_month = Month - 1
weeks = (months_before_current_month * 4.34524)//1 #//1 to round off the weeks as weeks can't be in  decimals
```

Subtract the current weeks, 9 in the first case

```
current_weeks = 9
weeks = current_weeks - weeks
```

I hope it works, Please Comment if it works